# SlidingTabLayout getCurrentItem() on onClick() drawer menu item

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-tabs

How to change current tab on **HomeActivity** when item on drawer menu is clicked?

View created on **SlidingTabsBasicFragment.java**. It called on **HomeActivity.java**
**DrawerMenu** in **HomeActivity**, so i need change current tab on **HomeActivity** when item on drawer menu is clicked.

PS: Sorry for my English :)

**HomeActivity.java**

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.tagwishes.fc.R.layout.activity_home);




    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();

        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }
```

...

i need something this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.tagwishes.fc.R.layout.activity_home);




    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();

        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    OnClickListener oclBtn = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //HOW TO GET mViewPager
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);// 3 FOR EXAMPLE

        }
    };


    btn.setOnClickListener(oclBtn);
```

**mViewPager** called in **SlidingTabsBasicFragment.class**

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (setup_viewpager)
    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());
    // END_INCLUDE (setup_viewpager)

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (setup_slidingtablayout)
    // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be done AFTER the ViewPager has had
    // it's PagerAdapter set.
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);



    //mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(R.color.bg_register);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    // END_INCLUDE (setup_slidingtablayout)




}
```

Comment: try static ViewPager instance it will surely work

Comment: Could you give example code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem:

so i copy **SlidingTabsBasicFragment.class** OnViewCreated() code to **HomeActivity.class** and remove **SlidingTabsBasicFragment.class**. Final HomeActivity.class

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.tagwishes.fc.R.layout.activity_home);



    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());

    // END_INCLUDE (setup_viewpager)

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (setup_slidingtablayout)
    // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be done AFTER the ViewPager has had
    // it's PagerAdapter set.
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);



    //mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(R.color.bg_register);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    // END_INCLUDE (setup_slidingtablayout)
```

and now i can implement oncliklistener and change selected tab with mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

Answer (score 0):

Add Listener `NavigationDrawer` layout. and associate with `ActionBarDrawerToggle`:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout /* your drawer layout reference */,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            /* do what you want with View Pager */
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item_id);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    });
```

ViewPager can be initialised in `onCreate()` :

```
ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.pagerId);
// add adapter
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter /* Your adapter */);
```

Comment: mViewPager already called in SlidingTabsBasicFragment.java . I need do mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position) in HomeActivity.